# Setting up domain alias CNAME record

Tags: dns, hosting, digital-ocean, cname

I have a website setup at `bryantmakesprog.10b3.com`. I also own the domain `sneaky.fish`. I want my domain to point to this website by pointing to to the url, NOT the ip address. The end result being that visiting `sneaky.fish/sample-page` renders `bryantmakesprog.10b3.com/sample-page` but the URL says `sneaky.fish/sample-page`.

What would be the best way to go about this? I've seen some people have CNAMEs setup, but I'm not having any luck. Here's what I've tried:

[image]

---

To clarify, the domain *must* point to the subdomain. It is not sufficient to point to `10b3.com`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there were two parts to this issue.

The first, the CNAMEs worked, it was just a matter of waiting.

The second issue was with the subdomain. `sneaky.fish` redirected to `10b3.com`, and only `bryantmakesprog.sneaky.fish` would redirect to `bryantmakesprog.10b3.com`.

The solution for this was to use PHP to determine if a CNAME record exists pointing to `bryantmakesprog.10b3.com` and to handle that accordingly.